# How to load an html page inside an existing html page

Tags: html

Good day!

I am creating a website that have several HTML pages. My main page is divided as follows using the `div` code:

[image: main page]

I've decided that the header, the left column and the footer will be same for all pages. Without using the `FRAMES` in html, Is it possible that when I click the BUTTON 1 (I used hyperlink code `<a href="Catalogue.jsp" class="widget" >Catalogue</a>`) the page called will be loaded inside the right column? I've read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564356/loading-html-page-inside-div) but I don't know which is the best solution to my problem (and honestly, i don't know how to insert it in my codes because I tried  this code `$("#mydiv").load("myexternalfile.html");` and it didn't work.. I think i am missing something.. How can i do the code, if i click the hyperlink, show this page inside the right column...).

Also, I am wondering if it is faster or more commonly used if I do this method instead of reloading the whole page everytime even though my header, leftcolumn, and footer will be the same for all of my pages. What will be the cons if i do this to all of my pages?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: my vote for this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564356/loading-html-page-inside-div/3564423#3564423 from the post you linked.

Comment: my link was to answer about jQuery solution, the one you  tried but without results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Without using the FRAMES in html, Is it possible that when I click the BUTTON 1 (I used hyperlink code `<a href="Catalogue.jsp" class="widget" >Catalogue</a>`) the page called will be loaded inside the right column?

There are iframes (which are just another type of frames), and there is the simulation of frames using JavaScript (Ajax techniques) which have all the drawbacks of frames plus some extra ones on top.

> `$("#mydiv").load("myexternalfile.html");` and it didn't work).

i.e. that.

It is hard to say why it failed without more information though.

> Also, I am wondering if it is faster

Slightly

> or more commonly used

Not common at all

> if I do this method instead of reloading the whole page everytime even though my header, leftcolumn, and footer will be the same for all of my pages.

HTML compresses really well, and templates save on manually duplicating the shared content. There are reasons why almost every website has distinct pages with shared meta content.

> What will be the cons if i do this to all of my pages?

It breaks bookmarking, search engine indexing, link sharing, and access for users without JavaScript.

Comment: Dorward So you are saying it is better if i just load the whole page?

Comment: Dorward Okay I'll heed you're advice and not to do my method anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use iFrame and do "display=block" conditionally or clicking on any button using javascript

`<iframe src="newpage.html" width="200" height="200"
frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" name="myInlineFrame" display=none></iframe>`