# Changing PHP variable from an <a href=""> link

Tags: php, html

I'm making a site using divs. I have one across the top with a row of links which I want to change what's in the main window. I would prefer to keep strictly to PHP and HTML and use a full page refresh as I am comfortable with them at current, rather than using an Ajax refresh as I don't have any knowledge of Ajax.

I don't want to use iframes. I thought the best way to do this would be as follows:

```
<div id="top">
<a href="news.html">News</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
<?php include($page); ?>
</div>
```

What I need is a way of changing the `$page` variable upon clicking the link.
If this means changing the variable and then reloading the page then so be it.

A command following the logic of:

```
<a href="news.html" action="<?php $page="news.html"; ?>">News</a>
```

would be ideal! I thought about using a form, but it seems there should be an easier way.

Comment: I think what is being asked here is how to load a new html / php page in a div. You can accomplish that using jQuery's load. See a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564356/loading-html-page-inside-div?rq=1)

Comment: you don't need to parse a variable you just need to examine what the current page is , this information will be it the $_SERVER array.

Comment: Or you can pass the target page as a GET parameter via `<a href="?target=news.html">` and `include($_GET['target']);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't *change* a variable, per se. Reloading the page means running the PHP program from scratch. You just have to provide it with different input. From a regular link, that is only possible through the URL.

```
<a href="foo.php?something=a_value">
```

Data in the query string is accessible via `$_GET`

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['something']);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a GET request on the same page,

```
<a href="news.html?page=news.html">News</a>
```

This will cause a page refresh on click, with the value for the page variable passed to php, and accessible through

```
$page = $_GET['page'] //at this point, $page will be "news.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, to change the include on the fly, as you are talking, you need to use AJAX, otherwise you need a full refresh.

Send data back to the server, with a normal link.

```
<a href="page.php?page=newpage.html">link</a>
```

Then you can use the $_GET variable of PHP, which is a array that parse the parameters for a URL page.

Example:

```
$page = $_GET['page']
include $page;
```

If you use jQuery, or want to try a easy AJAX method, you can search for [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

At the top of the PHP script. If your page is "somepage.php" the above will output

```
    /somepage.php
```

as the value of $page.

To get rid of the slash and .php just use substr:

```
    $page = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],1,-4);
```

which will leave you with $page = somepage